# How to track time spent on Web Site

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, time-tracking

In my rails application, I want to track the total time spent on site by individual user.
I did research on it but can not get perfect solution.
How is it possible.

Comment: how can I get the time when the window is closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

something like that?

```
var time,timeSite;
window.onload=function(){
 time=new Date();
}


window.onbeforeunload=function(){
 timeSite=new Date()-time;
 window.localStorage['timeSite']=timeSite;
 //store it with whatever serverside language.
}
```

if you want more add `window.onblur`

this code works.. also ajax would prolly work...

at extreme solution store it in localstorage(like in the example) and then on next login do the ajax.

this works gives you the exact time in seconds...

if you want approx time and for users who don't have localstorage add a setTimeout every 5 min

and update time passed if ajax & localstorage don't work.

---

here is a ajax call to test with inside the onbeforeunload function.

change `railsurl` whith whatever you need.

```
var x=new XMLHttpRequest;x.open('get','railsurl?time='+timeSite);x.send();
```

---

and as @Yiğitcan Uçum mentioned..

why not just use a serverside session to start and end the time spend on a site?

Comment: This is all fine and well, but how are you going to send that to somewhere else? For example, you can't do an AJAX request as the window would close before it completed.

Comment: window.onbeforeunload function call the function while the form is submit

Comment: My main problem is the AJAX call, is there any alternative method to do this.

Comment: you have tested ajax? localstorage is the most direct solution and works everytime. i use it with onbeforeunload.. on some scripts and never had problems.i personally didn't tested ajax .. but a fast XmlHttpRequest would also work prolly.you only need to send a small string

Comment: if you want i add you a proper ajax call for that... not using jquery obiovsly

Comment: @GaneshKunwar you need to think what you want before implementing this kind of tracking to your site. If you're looking for to track every page the person stayed on and if you want to get the exact time, you either need to do an interval(setInterval per x sec), orbeforeunload(this event is called when the web page is closed but if you have an ajax call in this event, browser will wait for your call to finish until closing the page). If you just want to get the statistics of regular users, you can do server side implementation with sessions.

Comment: @Yiğitcan Uçum thats what i already wrote.

Comment: @cocco i edited my comment. i forgot to add the serverside implementation info at the end. I guess my comment is clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var time,timeSite;

  window.onload = function(){
  time = new Date();
 }


   $(window).unload(function () {
     timeSite = new Date() - time;
     $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     async: false,
     data: {timespent: timeSite},
     url: '/url/to/rails.com'
   });
 });
```

Comment: I used: javascript:window.onbeforeunload = function ()

Answer (score 0):

The ***jquery*** `unload ()` event handler can be used to handle this situation,

***Example :***

Create a server side script say track.php to save all the collected tracking details into a db.

```
/*   Assuming you are tracking authenticated users the */
```

**In Javascript :**

```
var loggedInAt;
var loggedOutAt;

var userId = getUserId (); 

function getUserId () {
 return userId; // Define a mathod for getting the user if from a cookie or any local variables.
}

function getTotalTimeSpent() {
 return (loggedOutAt - loggedInAt);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  loggedInAt = Date.getTime(); // get the start time when the user logged in

  $(window).unload(function() {
      loggedOutAt = Date.getTime();
      totalTimeSpent = getTotalTimeSpent(loggedOutAt, loggedInAt);
      $.ajax({ 
        url: "www.yoursite.com/track.php",
        method:post,
        data: {'TotalTimeSpent': totalTimeSpent, 'UserId' : userId}
      })
    });
}
```

**In tracking.php :**

get the variables `$_REQUEST['TotalTimeSpent'] & $_REQUEST['UserId']` and make an insert query to relay the information into the db.

Thanks.